# using a mail() option on a server managed with cpanel

Tags: php, email, cpanel

Hi all i am really new at this and i have searched all over and cannot find a good guide or instructions on how to approach this.
So far i have been running my webpage only for test with WAMPP and i know in order to make MAIL() function to work you need to set up parameters in PHP.ini and use a mailclient like hmail. All that is behind me now.
So i have both a domain and i recived a CPanel interface to manage it. I also have mailserver now.
My question is where and how do i need to setup the SMTP credentials and how? I want users to be able to send mails from the webpage when clicking "send".

If any help this is my php code:

```
$to      = 'myemail@mydomainame.com';
$subject = 'prijava_na_tecaj';
$headers = "Ime: " . $update_ime . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Priimek: " . $update_priimek . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Email: " . $update_email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Telefon: " . $update_telefon . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Ime: " . $update_izobrazba . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Ime: " . $update_kraj . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Status: " . $id_sem_oseba . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $headers);

if(@mail($to, $subject, $headers)){
  echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
}else{
  echo "Mail Not Sent";
}
```

Comment: In cPanel you just create mail accounts, and then cPanel offers the SMTP settings as a link in that interface. Go check it out and you will see.

Comment: In most of shared hosting mail function is default enabled you can just start using it, If does not work you have to use PHPMailer class with SMTP

Comment: Hi Brian, i know and i know where that is but i dont know if you need to change something.
HI BSB, ok so if i enable the mail function then this would automaticly work? :O ok, i didnt know that

Answer (score 0):

It would advice you to use a library like phpmailer, here is the link https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer. This library provides all necessary aspects of how send emails. The `try` and `catch` will give you information about possible bugs sending emails.

To get credentials from cPanel, go to Email and create the email account since the mail will be send, then select this email and click on "Install email client". The credentials will be there, host, ports, smptSecure, etc.

An example here:

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                             // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```